# Issue with Swipe inside ListView

Tags: wpf, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-store

I am using a ListView in a Windows Store App.
Whenever I start swiping(using simulator tap mode) over the list view all the items move together as illustrated in the picture.
[image]
How can I disable this manipulation event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your `ListView`, add:

```
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
```

If that is not enough (this sometimes does not work with MouseWheel events, in that the events still tend to be caught in the ListView and also tends to happen if the list inside of the ScrollViewer is particularly large, I've found), then you need to create a custom control to specifically ignore the event, such as this for `PointerWheelChanged`.

```
public class CustomListView : ListView
{
    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        var sv = this.GetTemplateChild("ScrollViewer") as UIElement;
        if (sv != null)
            sv.AddHandler(UIElement.PointerWheelChangedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(OnPointerWheelChanged), true);
    }

    private void OnPointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = false;
    }
}
```

This will disable mouse wheel scrolling inside of your `ListView`. You'll have to change your XAML reference to the `ListView` from `<ListView>` to `<namespace:ListView>` where `namespace` is the namespace you've created your ListView in.